# What is wrong with my answer to Kattis Modulo?

Tags: php

I'm a PHP beginner and I am trying out the Modulo Kattis problem and my code works fine when I test it in my terminal but when I submit my solution I get 'Wrong answer'.

The problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/modulo):

*"Given two integers A and B, A modulo B is the remainder when dividing A by B. For example, the numbers 7, 14, 27 and 38 become 1, 2, 0 and 2, modulo 3. Write a program that accepts 10 numbers as input and **outputs the number of distinct numbers in the input, if the numbers are considered modulo 42.***

*If you fail on these, make sure that:
 - You are not printing any output other than the one specified in the
   problem
 - You have not misspelled any part of the output (copy-paste
   is your friend)
 - You are printing real-valued numbers with the
   precision requested in the problem"*

So if input is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 the answer is going to be 10 because the input numbers % 42 gives 10 different outputs.

I really don't understand what's wrong. Thanks a lot and here is my code:

```
$results = array();

while(sizeof($results) < 10) 
{ 
    fscanf(STDIN, '%d', $input);
    array_push($results, $input % 42); 
}

$unique = count(array_unique($results));
fprintf(STDOUT, "%d\n", $unique);
```

Comment: _when I submit my solution I get 'Wrong answer'...._ Submit to what?

Comment: Looks like it's this: https://open.kattis.com/problems/modulo

Comment: It may help if the question read well in english or any language. As it does not it is not completely obvious what is required

Comment: There's no need to assign `$unique` each time through the loop, although I don't think it should affect the result.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `fprintf` instead of just `echo`?

Comment: @Barmar Good point, thanks. And it was required for the problem to produce output with fprintf(STDOUT, ...).

Comment: Did you include the `<?php` line when you submitted it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Are you referring the poster's English or the problem specification at the Kattis site? I don't find either of them unclear, but I tend to be pretty forgiving if it seems like English isn't the poster's native language.

Comment: @Barmar the original question

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Similar to Barmar's comment: Check that your file begins with <?php. Any whitespace or data before the php tag will get printed out as whitespace and may disrupt the output. Best check the output by executing and redirecting the output to a file and verify the contents: `php modulo.php > out.txt`

Comment: I submitted the code (with the opening `<?php` included) to the site and it accepted the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, did not realise I was submitting without <?php.............stupid mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Converting [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924629/what-is-wrong-with-my-answer-to-kattis-modulo/73820033#comment98504526_55924629) to an answer, you need to use the `<?php` opening tag on your PHP submissions to Kattis. After this modification, OP's code passed submission, but for the sake of it, here's a simpler solution that uses the array keys to deduplicate the numbers after taking each modulus:

```php
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $n);
    $unique[$n%42] = 1;
}

echo count($unique) . "\n";
```